# How to convert a string to a stream of bits in java

Tags: java, string

How to convert a string to a stream of bits zeroes and ones
what i did i take a string then convert it to an array of char then i used method 
called forDigit(char,int) ,but it does not give me the character as a stream of 0 and 1
could you help please.
also how could i do the reverse from bit to a char. pleaes show me a sample

Answer (score 19):

Its easiest if you take two steps. String supports converting from String to/from byte[] and BigInteger can convert byte[] into binary text and back.

```
String text = "Hello World!";
System.out.println("Text: "+text);

String binary = new BigInteger(text.getBytes()).toString(2);
System.out.println("As binary: "+binary);

String text2 = new String(new BigInteger(binary, 2).toByteArray());
System.out.println("As text: "+text2);
```

Prints

```
Text: Hello World!
As binary: 10010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000010101110110111101110010011011000110010000100001
As text: Hello World!
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this one ..

```
public String toBinaryString(String s) {

    char[] cArray=s.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    for(char c:cArray)
    {
        String cBinaryString=Integer.toBinaryString((int)c);
        sb.append(cBinaryString);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that not all characters are the same length of bits set, so you wouldn't be able to decode this binary sequence as you won't know how long the bits are.

Comment: thanks bob.. ! @Peter Lawrey each character is encoded into binary string of length 7. So I guess.. it can be handled..

Comment: System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(' ')); prints 100000

Comment: @Peter let @bob2 come out with clear requirements if he faces any difficulty while executing, thankyou very much I'm working out to handle the same

Answer (score 0):

```
String strToConvert = "abc";
byte [] bytes = strToConvert.getBytes();
StringBuilder bits = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 8); 
System.err.println(strToConvert + " contains " + bytes.length +" number of bytes");
for(byte b:bytes) {
  bits.append(Integer.toString(b, 2));
}   

System.err.println(bits);
char [] chars = new char[bits.length()];
bits.getChars(0, bits.length(), chars, chars.length);
```