# Write bits in a file and retrieve them to a string of "0101.." in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles

I am working on a compression algorithm and for that i need to write strings of bits to a binary file and retrieve back exactly the same to a String again!
say, i have a string "10100100100....." and i will write them in a file as bits

> (not chars '0' '1')

. and read back as bits and convert to string...
and this is for a large amount of data (>100 megabytes).
is there any neat and fast way of doing this?

So far i tried (and failed) writing them to bytes by sub-stringing into 8 bits and then as ASCII characters to a string and finally to a .txt file.

```
{
    String Bits="10001010100000000000"; // a lot larger in actual program 

    String nCoded="";
    char nextChar;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < Bits.length()-8; i += 8){

        nextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt( Bits.substring(i, i+8), 2 );
        nCoded += nextChar;
    }

    // for the remainding bits, padding
    if(newBits.length()%8 != 0){
        nCoded+=(char)Integer.parseInt(Bits.substring(i), 2);
    }
    nCoded+=(char)Bits.length()%8; //to track the remainder of Bits that was padded 

    writeToTextFile( nCoded, "file.txt"); //write the nCoded string to file
}
```

but this seems to corrupt information and inefficient. 
again for clarification, i dont want the ***String*** to be written, its just a representation of the actual data. So, i want to

> convert each 0 and 1 from the string representation to its binary form
>   and write that to file.

Comment: Will the string always be a binary string?

Comment: Is it really necessary to ever have the bits in an actual `String`? That seems like an unnecessary complication. If you write them out while you generate them you could use a simple bit buffer in an int that you periodically flush.

Comment: yes. they will contain only 1s and 0s @DarshanMehta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to a stream of bits in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416954/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-stream-of-bits-in-java)

Comment: Do you know that `Bits.substring(i, i+7)` is only 7 characters long?

Comment: So a String version of "0" is not the same as a single bit 0. Are you wanting to convert each 0 and 1 from the string representation to its binary form and write that to file?

Comment: yes, exactly @pczeus

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for pointing that out, this may fix the current bug. Still i would prefer to have them written in a data file as bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method you can use to convert the String to a series of bits, ready for output to file:

```
private byte[] toByteArray(String input){
    //to charArray
    char[] preBitChars = input.toCharArray();
    int bitShortage = (8 - (preBitChars.length%8));
    char[] bitChars = new char[preBitChars.length + bitShortage];
    System.arraycopy(preBitChars, 0, bitChars, 0, preBitChars.length);

    for (int  i= 0;  i < bitShortage;  i++) {
        bitChars[preBitChars.length + i]='0';
    }

    //to bytearray
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[bitChars.length/8];
    for(int i=0; i<bitChars.length; i++) {
        if (bitChars[i]=='1'){
            byteArray[byteArray.length - (i/8) - 1] |= 1<<(i%8);
        }
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Passing the String "01010101" will return the result [85] as a byte[].

It turns out there is an easier way. There is a static `Byte.parseByte(String)` that returns `Byte` object. Calling:

```
 Byte aByte = Byte.parseByte("01010101");
 System.out.println(aByte);
```

Displays the same value: 85.

So you may ask a couple of questions here.

1. Why are we passing a String that is 8 characters in length. Well, you can prefix the String with an 9th character, that would represent a sign bit. I don't think you have this case, but if you needed to, the documentation for `Byte.parseByte()` states it should be:

> An ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.

So from this information, you would need to break up your String manually into 8 bit Strings and call `Byte.parseByte()` to get a `Byte` object for each.

2) What about writing bits to a file? No, file writing is done in bytes. If you need to write the file, then read it back in and convert back to a String, you will need to reverse the process and read the file in as a `byte[]` then convert that to it's String representation.

A Hint on how to convert a byte to a nice String format can be found here:

[Convert byte (java data type) value to bits (a string containing only 8 bits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364054/convert-byte-java-data-type-value-to-bits-a-string-containing-only-8-bits)

Comment: Why do you avoid the sign like that? There is no problem with using the sign bit as though it was a regular bit, and in fact java *requires* that because it has no unsigned bytes.

Comment: Yea ok but my point is, he has bytes, so there will have to 8 bits in them. Taking only every 7 out of 8 would result in too many bytes

Answer (score -1):

You can get an `InputStream` from a `String`, read each byte and write it to a file (byte is a smallest unit that you can read/write). Once everything is written, you can read the data in a similar way (i.e. `InputStream`) and use it. Below is an example:

```
String hugeSting = "10101010010101010110101001010101";
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(hugeSting.getBytes());
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Test.txt");
byte b;
while((b = (byte) in.read()) != -1){
    out.write(b);
}
in.close();
in = new FileInputStream("Test.txt");
//Read data
```

Comment: you got've it wrong. i don't want the String to be written, its just a representation of the binary data. I want to convert each 0 and 1 from the string representation to its binary form and write that to file.

Comment: As I said, you can't write a bit to a file. The smallest unit you can write is byte.